# In Mongoose+NodeJS is pushing an object into array the same as pushing the objectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In Mongoose Schema's which involve Users, we sometimes see something like this:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  followers: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}] 
});
```

If somewhere in my code, I want to add a follower, are the following two statements equivalent?

**First possibility**

```
var aUser = new User();
var anOtherUser = new User();
aUser.followers.push(anOtherUser); //Push the user object
```

**Second Possibility**

```
var aUser = new User();
var anOtherUser = new User();
aUser.followers.push(anOtherUser._id); //Push the id directly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing the codes with `UserSchema`, the results are same.

Codes 1

```
var aUser = new User();
var anOtherUser = new User();
aUser.followers.push(anOtherUser);
```

Result,

```
aUser --> { "_id" : ObjectId("56f49865a09d6dc824343704"), "followers" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
anOtherUser --> { "_id" : ObjectId("56f49865a09d6dc824343703"), "followers" : [ ObjectId("56f49865a09d6dc824343704") ], "__v" : 0 }
```

---

Codes 2:

```
var aUser = new User();
var anOtherUser = new User();
aUser.followers.push(anOtherUser._id);
```

Result:

```
aUser --> { "_id" : ObjectId("56f49a07c4b56cc0285d2da1"), "followers" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
anOtherUser --> { "_id" : ObjectId("56f49a07c4b56cc0285d2da0"), "followers" : [ ObjectId("56f49a07c4b56cc0285d2da1") ], "__v" : 0 }
```

The codes2 snippet is correct way to add `ObjectId` to `followers` per [Mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).